# MySQL - Return from function only if single row matches

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a MySQL table of users as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `ID` INT NOT NULL, -- NOTE: in practice, I'm using BINARY(16) and
                       --       the UUID()-function to create user IDs.
                       --       'INT' is only a simplification for this
                       --       stackoverflow question.

    `FirstName` NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `LastName` NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    -- ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

INSERT INTO `users` (`ID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`)
VALUES (0, 'Albus', 'Dumbledore'),
       (1, 'Lord', 'Voldemort'),
       (2, 'Harry', 'Potter'),
       (3, 'Hermione', 'Granger');
```

I'd like to create a user-defined function which returns the `ID` of the row matching a `FirstName` and `LastName` combination if (and only if) the results are unique (i.e. only one row matches the query):

```
CREATE FUNCTION `FindUser`(`first_name` NVARCHAR(100), `last_name` NVARCHAR(100)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT `ID`
            FROM `users`
            WHERE ((first_name is NULL) OR (`FirstName` LIKE CONCAT('%', first_name, '%')))
            AND ((last_name Is NULL) OR (`LastName` LIKE CONCAT('%', last_name, '%')))
            LIMIT 1);
END
```

This works as expected on the following examples:

```
SELECT `FindUser`(NULL, 'potter');
-- | ID |
-- |----|
-- |  2 |

SELECT `FindUser`('obama', NULL);
-- | ID |
-- |----|
```

However, this does not work on `SELECT FindUser(NULL, 'or');`, as the token `'or'` could match `0 | Albus | Dumbledore` and `1 | Lord | Voldemort`.

---

I tried the following:

```
SET @cnt = 0;
SET @id = NULL;

SELECT @id = u.id, @cnt = COUNT(id)
FROM users u
WHERE ...; -- same conditions as before

RETURN IF(@cnt = 1, @id, NULL);
```

However, that does not work, as `@id` and `@cnt` will always be overwritten by the last line.
The alternative would be to perform two queries, but that is inefficient.

**How could I solve the problem most efficiently?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing you're using a MySql version that supports *window functions* a simple modification you can make is to conditionally count the number of rows:

```
RETURN (
  SELECT CASE WHEN count(*) over() = 1 then ID ELSE null END
  FROM users
  WHERE (first_name is NULL OR FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%', first_name, '%'))
    AND (last_name Is NULL OR LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', last_name, '%'))
  LIMIT 1
);
```

Demo [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nYOGDxOX)

Answer (score 1):

You could use aggregation and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FindUser(first_name NVARCHAR(100), last_name NVARCHAR(100))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (
    SELECT MAX(ID) 
    FROM users
    WHERE (first_name IS NULL OR FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%', first_name, '%'))
      AND (last_name IS NULL OR LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', last_name, '%'))
    GROUP BY NULL -- you can omit this clause 
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  );
END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CcuQNvd0).

I suspect that for the edge case where there is only 1 row in the table and the parameters that you pass for the function are both `null` you don't want the `ID` of that row returned.
For this case you should add one more condition in the `WHERE` clause to make sure that at least one of the parameters is not `null`:

```
WHERE (first_name IS NOT NULL OR last_name IS NOT NULL)
  AND (first_name IS NULL OR FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%', first_name, '%'))
  AND (last_name IS NULL OR LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', last_name, '%'))
```

Comment: in paractice, I am using `BINARY(16)` and `UUID()` as IDs for the users, I only used `INT` IDs for this stackoverflow question. The `Max(...)`-function would not work in this case, would it?

Comment: @unknown6656 MAX works fine on UUIDs: https://dbfiddle.uk/vKBJOEjO but not on BINARY.

Comment: oh ok, that's perfect then. Thank you!